# Command to easily create alias

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I'm looking for a simple command that would allow me to create a terminal alias to another command from the command line and preferably use it without having to restart my terminal.

The use case is as follows, I just created a small bash script and put it on gist.

```
# Babel in your project
npm i json -g
npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
json -f package.json -I -e 'this.scripts.test = "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive"'
json -f package.json -I -e 'this.babel = {}'
json -f package.json -I -e 'this.babel.presets = ["es2015", "react"]'
json -f package.json -I -e 'this.main = "./lib/index"'
json -f package.json -I -e 'this.esnext = "./src/index"'
```

I can run it here from the terminal like this:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/8035dcbdf0fb73b8c8703a4d244f15cf/raw/767ec8c2fb54b554ce122cc85953da5b277dbaf4/babel-ready.sh)"
```

I'm curious if there's an easily way to create an `alias` from the terminal. Something simple like:

```
add-alias babel-ready -- bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/8035dcbdf0fb73b8c8703a4d244f15cf/raw/767ec8c2fb54b554ce122cc85953da5b277dbaf4/babel-ready.sh)"
```

Comment: What exactly do you want `add-alias` to do?  If it should add the alias to `.bashrc` and make it available in the current shell, it is not entirely trivial.  If it is simply supposed to create an alias in the current shell, you'd simply use `alias`, wouldn't you?  If it is to add the alias to the current shell, it is going to need to be a (function? or) alias itself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want a permanent global alias. What do you mean by not entirely trivial?

Comment: @ThomasReggi, it'd be easy to give you an answer that would work for *most* systems and configurations, but an answer that will *always* work (and ideally be idempotent, ie. not modifying your `bashrc` file if the alias already exists) requires being able to parse and understand the code flow of your rc files, which is next to impossible.

Comment: That said, another issue here is that your alias would need to be escaped before it could be passed to any function we provide here -- ie. if it uses literal `"$(curl ...)"` commands, the user would be responsible for quoting those so they aren't evaluated before being passed to the command, or else the command couldn't possibly see the original pre-expansion command content.

Comment: ...btw, in general, it's usually preferable to use a shell function rather than an alias unless you're in a case where you specifically need prefix substitution. Functions are considerably more capable: they can actually perform conditional logic, f'rinstance, in deciding which command to pass your arguments through to.

Answer (score 0):

A rough attempt (not flow-control aware, not idempotent, not able to recognize and remove old versions of the same alias) might look something like this:

```
# non-POSIX-compliant function keyword used to allow dash in function name
function add-alias() {
  # declare locals explicitly to prevent scope leakage
  local content_line cmd

  (( $# == 1 )) && [[ $1 ]] || {
    echo "Usage: add_alias name" >&2
    return 1
  }
  IFS= read -r content_line

  # reject inputs containing newlines
  content_line=${content_line%$'\n'}
  if [[ $content_line = *$'\n'* ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Only one line may be provided" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  # generate a command
  printf -v cmd "alias %q=%q" "$1" "$content_line"

  # eval it in the local shell, and add to the rc if that succeeds
  eval "$cmd" && printf '%s\n' "$cmd" >>"$HOME/.bashrc"
}
```

...used as:

```
add-alias babel-ready <<'EOF'
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/reggi/8035dcbdf0fb73b8c8703a4d244f15cf/raw/767ec8c2fb54b554ce122cc85953da5b277dbaf4/babel-ready.sh)"
EOF
```

---

Note the use of `<<'EOF'` -- quoting the heredoc is important, as this prevents expansions from being run when the alias is being defined (as opposed to when it's run). This is why usage is passing code on stdin rather than on the command line, which would make it the user's responsibility to quote command line arguments appropriately.